# Vba Add Collection into object property

Tags: vba, properties

How can I add collection into the object.property ? It keeps giving me an error. What am I doing wrong?
I wanna get a tree structure, I mean inside one property(for example value) would be a collection which has another objects with collections...

```
Option Explicit

Public name As String
Public value As Variant
Public ValueType As String
Public valueHelp As Collection

Function addColl()

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To 5
        Dim nextCollection As Collection
        Set nextCollection = New Collection
        Dim obj1 As JsonElement
        Set obj1 = New JsonElement


        obj1.name = "City" & i
        obj1.value = "type"
        obj1.ValueType = nextCollection
        nextCollection.Add obj1
        'obj1.valueHelp = nextCollection
        'nextCollection.Add nextCollection

    Next

End Function
```

Comment: What error is it giving you, and which line is causing it?

Comment: if valueType is as Collection then
"Object Variable or with block variable not set"
in
obj1.valueType = nextCollection
and if valueType is a Variant then
"Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment"

Comment: have you tried `Set obj1.ValueType = nextCollection`

Comment: You're assigning a collection to a String variable. You're "missing" the `Set` keyword for assigning objects, but once you add it you'll just get another error (bc you can't assign a collection to a String). If I'm reading right, you want to have a collection that contains an object, one of whose properties is the collection it belongs to? I'd love to hear about the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you just have to replace this line:

```
obj1.ValueType = nextCollection
```

with this line:

```
Set obj1.ValueType = nextCollection
```

since the object type of the property you are trying to store a value in (type Collection) cannot implicitly call the `Set` keyword as it does with strings or integers.